# How do I git rebase the first commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I used `git init` to create a fresh repo, then made three commits. Now I want to rebase to go back and amend my first commit, but if I do `git rebase -i HEAD~3` it shows error - `fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'`!

If I try the same with `HEAD~2` then it kinda works but only lets me rearrange the last two commits.

How do I refer to the 'commit before there were any commits' or go back and insert an empty commit?

---

ERROR  with `git rebase -i HEAD~3`:

```
fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git)

Comment: [Checkout the first commit and amend it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2119656/9157799)

Answer (score 882, accepted):

The easy way, with a recent-enough Git (this has been out for a long time now so you should have this):

```
git rebase -i --root
```

The other easy way, as [twalberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253222/twalberg) noted in a comment that has since been deleted but is now expanded in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68279810/1256452's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68279810/1256452), is to use `git checkout --orphan` to set up to make a new root commit, which you can copy the old commits on top of.  (This is what `rebase -i --root` ends up doing internally anyway.)  For some purposes, such as splitting what had been the initial commit, this initial blank commit is helpful.

Side note from the future (2022): It's often a good idea to make the very first commit contain just a few boilerplate files like a `README`.  The very first commit in any new, empty repository is always a bit special.  Note that if you use hosting sites like Bitbucket, GitHub, and GitLab, they will often make such an initial commit *for* you when you create a repository there, so that you can clone the repository thus created and have a starting point.

Comment: Using `git rebase -i --root` I get the error `error: cannot 'fixup' without a previous commit` when attempting to squash the second commit (I just want the first)

Comment: What exactly are you editing into the instruction sheet? You should have a list of commits, with oldest at the top, and command `pick` for each one. Change the *second* `pick` to either `squash` or `fixup`, write out the instruction sheet, exit your editor, and Git should do the job.

Comment: This is blowing up for me too.  What version of git does this work on?

Comment: @Jason: it's been in since 1.6.2 or 1.7.12 (the basic `--root` went in with Git 1.6.2, an improved version went in at 1.7.12). What do you mean by "blowing up"?

Comment: After farting around with different strategies for 20 minutes the error cleared itself. I have unfortunately lost the exact message. Something about todo.

Comment: Love this command. Never been able to get it to work without modifying the metadata of all subsequent commits. Though I suppose that could be considered a feature.

Comment: @Jason The message would be something along the lines of “error: cannot 'fixup' without a previous commit You can fix this with 'git rebase --edit-todo' and then run 'git rebase --continue'. Or you can abort the rebase with 'git rebase --abort'.”.

Answer (score 24):

[torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000315/650249) is fine if you want to make changes to files that are already in the commit, edit the author/message, etc. But if you want to split the commit or anything like that, then chances are you're going to run into trouble because you can't do `git reset HEAD~` from the initial commit.

To make this possible, you can insert an empty initial commit like so:

```
git checkout --orphan empty-initial-commit
git rm -r --cached .
git clean -d -f
git commit --allow-empty -m 'Empty initial commit'
git checkout <branch>
git rebase empty-initial-commit
git branch -d empty-initial-commit
```

then you can do `git rebase -i`, edit the commit (the first non-empty commit), and do `git reset HEAD~` like normal.

Comment: tokek's answer worked fine for me for adding a file. You're either wrong or you're incomplete (the "or anything like that" doesn't include adding/removing files)

Comment: This worked like a charm. I think you need to un-stage all the files and run `git clean -fd` before the empty commit step to ensure the commit will be empty.

Comment: Nice pick-up @tarekahf. I've updated the commands to include those steps.

Comment: It *is* possible to split up the root commit without making an extra commit, but this method is likely a lot easier and therefore better for most people. :-) (I got brought back here by a recent comment and just noticed this answer; upvoted now)

Comment: nb: this might fail because of pre-commit hooks