# How to change the default first commit message when using a GitHub template?

Tags: github, git-commit, repo

When I create a new GitHub repository from my [GitHub template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template), the first git commit message is automatically set to this:

> Initial commit

How can I override this? I couldn't find a way to change the initial commit message in the settings.

Comment: I don't think you can. Use the command line to create the first commit, where you have control.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this with a GitHub Action that defines the `on.create` field like this:

```yaml
# The workflow will run only when `use this template` is used
on:
  create:
```

See how I managed to do this in my [foundry-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/foundry-template/blob/main/.github/workflows/create.yml) project.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution? I understand [your code](https://github.com/paulrberg/foundry-template/blob/main/.github/workflows/create.yml) ends up calling `git commit --amend`. However, according to the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#create), the event `create` triggers not (specifically) when a repository is created from a template, but whenever a git reference (branch or tag) is created. How does your workflow not run every time you push a new branch or tag?

Comment: @djsp It might be true that the workflow runs on every new branch or tag, but in my scenario, I don't mind that, because I am only maintaining a `main` branch, and no tags. However, I don't see why this should be a problem anyway, because of the [check on line 12](https://github.com/paulrberg/foundry-template/blob/main/.github/workflows/create.yml#L12), which ensures that the workflow is never run in the template repo itself.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment by @torek, you cannot change the commit message from GitHub Web app directly, you can do it once you clone it in your system using a cli using [`git rebase -i --root`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000315/6908282). You can refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSRAuWgqYx0) for instructions

Below is the steps you need to follow:

1. Clone the repository locally & Open the folder of the repository in a terminal or your favorite IDE with an integrated terminal
2. run the following command in the terminal `git rebase -i --root`

   - This displays all the list of commits in your repository to let you edit (screenshot below).
3. hit the <kbd>i</kbd> key in your keyboard which starts the edit more
4. Go to your first commit in the list of commits and replace `pick` with `reword`
5. Hit Escape to stop editing
6. Type `:wq` on your keyboard (to write and quit) and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   - This finally opens up the commit allowing you to change the commit message
7. Make the change to the commit message and type `:wq` on your keyboard

   - This makes the changes in you local repository
8. Thats it, now you can push your changes to your remote repository with `git push --force`

   - you need to use `--force`.

[image: Screenshot of git rebase command from terminal]